# PrimeNG Datatable, paginator items per page not changing datatable when modified

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, primeng, primeng-datatable

The PrimeNG data table is not updating and changing the number of displayed items when the items per page dropdown is changed.

There are no console errors or any indication there is something set wrong.

`<p-dataTable #dt [value]="bols" exportFilename="bols" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedBol" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20" [responsive]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" [contextMenu]="cm"  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30,40,50]">`

I have not configured a callback to handle the change since I did not believe that this was necessary. Once the items per page is changed navigation to any other page does resize the result set appropriately.

Thanks

Comment: The paginator options appear to be set correctly.  Can you duplicate on plnkr?

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce in plnkr.  I am not having much luck.  I will keep building out the sample with mocks and see if I can replicate the majority of the component and parent in plnkr.  Hopefully, then I can break it there.